# how to save an image file in android?

Tags: android

I want save an image file in android, and the system gallery can view it or delete it. I use the following code, but found gallery could not find it,let alone view it or delete it. Any suggestion?

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap){
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + getString(R.string.folderName));
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem? If you want to open the Gallery why are you sending a broadcast, you can just create the intent and call startActivity().

Comment: @YuriiTsap I don't want to open the Gallery, just want that the saved images file can be viewed or deleted in the Gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line :

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

To:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, 
             Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want gallery to scan and add your app image folder then try this code after you save the image.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,new String[] { imagePath }, null,
    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    if(Config.LOG_DEBUG_ENABLED) {
        // if required do something after the scan complet
        Log.d(TAG, "scanned : " + path);
    }
}
```